# facebook api call limit

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, xfbml

recently we have been reaching the api call limit for Facebook.  One thing that look like it was very excessive is all the calls comming from the fxbml like buttons, some pages have up to 30 like buttons on them , they look like this in html:

```
<fb:like href="..." ... />
```

and for each one the browser makes a call to Facebook, something like this

```
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=11111111&locale=en_US& ....
```

This call is because, I'm assuming Facebook renders a different button whether or not the user has already liked the url. Does anyone know - do these calls count towards the number of calls you are allowed to make per AuthToken?

Comment: I can't find any documentation but from experience I am fairly sure that there is no limit on like button rendering.

Comment: @DanielWilliams , I don't know , there is a limit of 600 calls per 600 seconds per AuthToken and that is the only way I could imagine we are going over , each time the page refreshes that is 30 , i can't imagine the user is clicking on a button making a call faster then once a second for 10 minutes straight